# How do I use the dim function to evaluate another dataframe using mutate in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, mutated

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe that has the dimension of a portion of another dataframe using the following code.

```
library(dplyr)

dfa <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), sym=c("a","a","b","b","b"))
dfa <- dfa %>% group_by(sym)

dfb <- data.frame( sym = c("a", "b") )
dfb %>% mutate( len = dim( dfa[ dfa[["sym"]]==sym , ] )[1] )
```

This code give the unintended output and warning message:

```
  sym len
1   a   2
2   b   2
Warning message:
Problem while computing `len = dim(dfa[dfa[["sym"]] == sym, ])[1]`.
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The output I want is (I must use mutate)

```
  sym len
1   a   2
2   b   3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `dfa %>% count(sym, name = 'len')` or `dfa %>% group_by(sym) %>% summarise(len = n())`

Comment: The issue results from the comparison with `==`. You are trying to compare a vector of length 5 to a vector of length 2. That is not possible. Usually, this error message means that you actually want to use `%in%` and not `==`.

Comment: I must use ```mutate```.

Is there a solution that makes the variable sym behave like the column value (not the entire column itself) as mutate usually does?  For example, like ```dfb %>% mutate(z = str_length(sym) )``` which outputs 1's.

Comment: why do you have to use mutate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dfb %>% group_by(sym) %>% mutate(len=sum(sym == dfa$sym))
  sym     len
  <chr> <int>
1 a         2
2 b         3
```

The key is to group `dfb` by `sym` as well.